# File not found while loading Tiled map (libgdx)

Tags: java, parsing, dictionary, libgdx, tiled

I'm desperately seeking for help. Searched already everywhere, can't find an answer.
I'm trying to load tmx Tiled map with libgdx. I have no idea what's wrong, this is an exception:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: level1.tmx
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:83)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:80)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:67)
    at com.mygdx.game.PlayScreen.<init>(PlayScreen.java:35)
    at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:30)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:149)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: level1.tmx (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.reader(FileHandle.java:163)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:81)
...
```

and this is my code:

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
    private MyGdxGame game;
    private Texture texture;
    private OrthographicCamera gamecam;
    private Viewport gamePort; 
    private Hud hud;

    private TiledMap map;
    private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

    public PlayScreen(MyGdxGame game) {
        this.game = game;
        gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();
        gamePort = new FitViewport(MyGdxGame.V_WIDTH, MyGdxGame.V_HEIGHT, gamecam);

        hud = new Hud(game.batch);

        mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
        map = mapLoader.load("level1.tmx"); //THIS file cannot be found...
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
        gamecam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    public void handleInput(float dt) {
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched())
            gamecam.position.x += 100 * dt;
    }

    public void update(float dt) {
        handleInput(dt);

        gamecam.update();
        renderer.setView(gamecam);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        renderer.render();

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
        hud.stage.draw();

    }
//lines above are potentially bad
...
       }
```

level1.tmx and proper tileset.png file sit together in assets folder.

Tried also remaking the map with another tileset - got the same error. I see 'level1.tmx' in the project view window, in assets folder, 100% sure they are there. Using Android Studio.
Exception above is thrown while I'm trying to run program in desktop. As I'm trying to do so in android, it's all fine, compiled and built, but there's no map rendered and I see nothing except the black screen.
Hope there's a person who could help me, regards:)

Comment: Try different tilemap

Comment: @icarumbas already tried it. Problem still exists.

Comment: @spectral Are you able to use any other file from `assets` folder on your desktop ?

Comment: You're running using `gradle` task or by `Run/Debug` configuration.

Comment: @Aryan yes, other files work perfectly. I'm running the program using Run/Debug. Still need some help :(

Comment: please post content of `level1.tmx` file

Comment: @Aryan this is the original file: https://github.com/BrentAureli/SuperMario/blob/master/android/assets/level1.tmx

Comment: Note: I do have tileset_gutter.png in the same folder with level1.tmx, also tried with another tileset and another tmx map and it didn't help.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your Run/Debug configuration?

Comment: Basically my hunch is that your workingDirectory needs to be set to the assets folder in your Run configuration.

Comment: @JKLy I have already changed this and it's just like you said. Now I can run desktop app without exceptions. However, map still doesn't render and I see nothing but a black screen.

Comment: Don't you provide tileMapLoader.load() with a gdx file handle like this?

***TileMapLoader.load(gdx.files.internal("level1.tmx"))***